# Do I need to unzip the ISO to burn it?

Tags: iso, burning

I have successfully:

- Downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit Installation file
- Unzipped the file using WinZip
- Burned the unzipped files to a DVD, using Sonic RecordNow

I am experiencing the following difficulties:

- The DVD is not bootable
- When I manually try to execute wubi.exe, I get a message saying "An installable Virtual Device Driver failed Dll initialization.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I get Ubuntu to run?

Comment: Don't unzip the file, just burn the [ISO](http://www.imgburn.com/) to a DVD or create a [bootable](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)USB.

Answer (score 1):

The iso file, is an image of the disk, it was meant to be burned directly into the CD/DVD, without modification, nor uncompressing (actually the iso is not compressed itself).

You need some software to burn the iso into the disk (Windows Vista onwards can burn ISO without help). Just right click the file and look for "Burn to Disk" or "Burn Image".

There are tools for almost all OS's to burn ISO's:

- Windows: has both built-in and ImgBurn.
- Mac OSX: Disk Utility.
- Linux: has Brasero (just to mention the most popular... I think).

Comment: Dang, beat me by a couple of seconds. Just adding that the feature may also be called "Burn image".

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio hahaha, I had time to edit the question, fix the tags, think about a good title and then answer it >:D